# Why is there a mismatch in the value inside the function and outside the function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to store an array of pointers to a node. In the createlist() function, I have initialized the array of pointers with
`linked_list_array[i] = createNode(-1);` for each item in the array.

Then I assigned it to `list->linkedLists` with `list->linkedLists = linked_list_array`.
It seems that once I return `list` back into the main function, the value of `list->linkedLists[0]->key` changed.
Why is it that the value changed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NEG_INF (-32727)

struct leapList{
    
    int maxHeight;
    int curr_height;
    struct Node **linkedLists;
    double prob;
};

struct Node{
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* below;
    int key;
};

struct Node* createNode(int key){
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->below = NULL;
    new_node->key = key;
    return new_node;
}


struct leapList* createList(int maxheight, double p){
    struct leapList* list = (struct leapList*)malloc(sizeof(struct leapList));
    list->maxHeight = maxheight;
    list->prob = p;
    list->curr_height = 0;
    struct Node* linked_list_array[maxheight];
    for(int i=0;i<maxheight;i++){
        linked_list_array[i] = createNode(-1);
    }
    list->linkedLists = (linked_list_array);
    printf("key inside function: %d\n", list->linkedLists[0]->key);
    return list;
}
struct Node* insertNode(struct Node** headref, int key){
    struct Node* curr_node = NULL;
    struct Node* new_node = createNode(key);
    if(*headref == NULL || (*headref)->key >= key){
        new_node->next = *headref;
        *headref = new_node;
    }else{
        curr_node = *headref;
        while(curr_node->next!=NULL && curr_node->next->key < key){
            curr_node = curr_node->next;
        }
        new_node->next = curr_node->next;
        curr_node->next = new_node;
    }
    //printf("%d ", new_node->key);
    return new_node;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    struct leapList* list = createList(5, 0.5);
    printf("key outside function: %d", list->linkedLists[0]->key);
    struct Node* head_node = createNode(-37273);

    
    insertNode(&head_node, 5);
    insertNode(&head_node, 3);
    insertNode(&head_node, 1);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I get after running the program

[image: This is what I get after running the program]

Comment: The `below` confuses me. In a double-linked list I would expect a "previous". Is that it?

Comment: Your `linked_list_array` array of pointers is a **local** variable; when the `createList` function returns, that no longer exists.

Comment: @Yunnosch `below` isn't actually used. Probably a vestige of the full program, or something that will be used when the program is complete. Just pretend it's not there for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `list->linkedLists` to point to a local ("automatic storage") variable.

```c
...
struct Node* linked_list_array[maxheight];
...
list->linkedLists = linked_list_array;
...
```

It's no longer legal to access `linked_list_array` after the function returns, yet that's what you end up doing. This is Undefined Behaviour.

You will need to `malloc` the array.